# What language are most Linux GUI applications written in?

Tags: linux, user-interface, programming-languages

I apologize if this is off topic. Please close if it is.

I want to get in to a bit of Linux application development. What programming language are the majority of GUI apps made in?

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not sure there's a good way to answer this. perhaps if you could narrow down where to look, and hopefully make it more of a programming question: e.g. edit your question to ask "what is the most common language used to develop the 20 or so most popular GUI applications in the latest Debian stable repository, and what are the particular advantages of that language over others that make it popular?" dunno. something like that.

Comment: I have found out about Glade and the Vala programming language recently. I think it also depends on the distro that you're using. I mean, some distros prefer you use a particular language, and some distros have a "main" language. For example, in Elementary OS, it's more common (as I've read) that people use Vala to create GUI apps. I was just reading a tutorial about it, and it's actually quite simple and quick to setup: http://demonicode.ghoster.io/how-to-write-a-gui-app-with-glade-interface-designer-and-vala/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It usually largely depends on the [DE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) (desktop environment) you are focusing on; each usually has one GUI toolkit that it's using the most.

For instance, [GNOME](http://gnome.org/) mostly uses [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/); and since GTK+ is written in C, many Linux GTK+ GUI apps use that, but there are also bindings to other languages, like Python, which I've also seen used often. And there are bindings for other languages too.

On the other hand you have [KDE](http://kde.org/), which is mostly based on [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/); and, since Qt is written in C++, most apps using Qt are also written in C++.

However, honestly the choice of language doesn't matter much; it's more the toolkit that matters. I'd pick the one your DE uses, and then choose one of the languages it supports.